# In Loom, can I use virtual threads for Recursive[Action/Task]?

Tags: java, fork-join, project-loom, structured-concurrency

Is it possible to use RecursiveAction, for example, in conjunction with -- instead of the fork/join pool -- a pool of virtual threads (before I attempt a poorly-designed, custom effort)?

Comment: I'll need to learn more about RecursiveAction but a red-flag in your question is on pooling virtual threads. A major theme in the videos/articles on Loom is that virtual threads should not be pooled. They are cheap; a commodity.

Comment: that's true, though I'm interested in the provided functionality of Recursive*, having more theads to work with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`RecursiveAction`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/RecursiveAction.html) is a subclass of [`ForkJoinTask`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinTask.html) which is, as the name suggests and the documentation even says literally, an

> Abstract base class for tasks that run within a [`ForkJoinPool`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html).

While the [`ForkJoinPool`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html) can be [customized with a thread factory](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html#%3Cinit%3E(int,java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.ForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory,java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler,boolean)), it’s not [the standard thread factory](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ThreadFactory.html), but [a special factory](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.ForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory.html) for producing [`ForkJoinWorkerThread`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinWorkerThread.html) instances. Since these threads are subclasses of `Thread`, they can’t be created with the virtual thread factory.

So, you can’t use [`RecursiveAction`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/RecursiveAction.html) with virtual threads. The same applies to `RecursiveTask`. But it’s worth rethinking what using these classes with virtual threads would gain you.

The main challenge, to implement decomposition of your task into sub-task is on you, anyway. What these classes provide you, are features specifically for dealing with the Fork/Join pool and balancing the workload with the available platform threads. When you want to perform each sub-task on its own virtual thread, you don’t need this. So you can easily implement a recursive task with virtual threads without the built-in classes, e.g.

```java
record PseudoTask(int from, int to) {
    public static CompletableFuture<Void> run(int from, int to) {
        return CompletableFuture.runAsync(
            new PseudoTask(from, to)::compute, Thread::startVirtualThread);
    }

    protected void compute() {
        int mid = (from + to) >>> 1;
        if(mid == from) {
            // simulate actual processing with potentially blocking operations
            LockSupport.parkNanos(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toNanos(500));
        }
        else {
            CompletableFuture<Void> sub1 = run(from, mid), sub2 = run(mid, to);
            sub1.join();
            sub2.join();
        }
    }
}
```

This example just doesn’t care about limiting the subdivision nor avoiding blocking `join()` calls and it still performs well when running, e.g. `PseudoTask.run(0, 1_000).join();` You might notice that with larger ranges, the techniques known from the other recursive task implementations can be useful here too, where the sub-task is rather cheap.

E.g., you may only submit one half of the range to another thread and process the other half locally, like

```java
record PseudoTask(int from, int to) {
    public static CompletableFuture<Void> run(int from, int to) {
        return CompletableFuture.runAsync(
            new PseudoTask(from, to)::compute, Thread::startVirtualThread);
    }

    protected void compute() {
        CompletableFuture<Void> f = null;
        for(int from = this.from, mid; ; from = mid) {
            mid = (from + to) >>> 1;
            if (mid == from) {
                // simulate actual processing with potentially blocking operations
                LockSupport.parkNanos(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toNanos(500));
                break;
            } else {
                CompletableFuture<Void> sub1 = run(from, mid);
                if(f == null) f = sub1; else f = CompletableFuture.allOf(f, sub1);
            }
        }
        if(f != null) f.join();
    }
}
```

which makes a notable difference when running, e.g. `PseudoTask.run(0, 1_000_000).join();` which will use only 1 million threads in the second example rather than 2 millions. But, of course, that’s a discussion on a different level than with platform threads where neither approach would work reasonably.

---

Another upcoming option is the [`StructuredTaskScope`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/jdk.incubator.concurrent/jdk/incubator/concurrent/StructuredTaskScope.html) which allows to spawn sub-tasks and wait for their completion

```java
record PseudoTask(int from, int to) {
    public static void run(int from, int to) {
        try (var scope = new StructuredTaskScope.ShutdownOnFailure()) {
            new PseudoTask(from, to).compute(scope);
            scope.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
    }

    protected Void compute(StructuredTaskScope<Object> scope) {
        for(int from = this.from, mid; ; from = mid) {
            mid = (from + to) >>> 1;
            if (mid == from) {
                // simulate actual processing with potentially blocking operations
                LockSupport.parkNanos(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toNanos(500));
                break;
            } else {
                var sub = new PseudoTask(from, mid);
                scope.fork(() -> sub.compute(scope));
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Here, the tasks do not wait for the completion of their sub-task but only the root task waits for the completion of all tasks. But this feature is in incubator state, hence, may take even longer than the virtual threads feature, to become production-ready.

Comment: Very detailed. Many thanks.

Comment: Is it possible to use `StructuredTaskScope` with fixed threadpool? Or is it only intended to be used with unlimited virtual thread pool?

Comment: The intention is to use it with an unbounded number of virtual threads. But virtual threads are executed on a fixed platform thread pool behind the scenes.